# Hide a div if sibling has an specific class

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement, hide

I have a div with the `grafico` class, and it has two children. One of them, the one with "terminal-alert" class, should not appear if it's sibling, the `grafico-arc` has the specific "green" class.
I tried the jquery below, and managed to hide the "terminal-alert" div, but it does not appear on the ones where the sibling doesn't have the "green" class.

```js
$(".grafico-arc").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("green")) {
    $(".terminal-alert").siblings().css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc green">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>1 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc yellow">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>2 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc red">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>3 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might not be the way you wish to do this since you specified jQuery, but I want to leave this here anyway. (a jQuery version is further down)

**CSS Version:**

You can accomplish the same principal **using only CSS** with the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

> "The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first element, and both are children of the same parent element."

```css
.grafico-arc.green + .terminal-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderCard">
    <div class="grafico">
        <div class="grafico-arc green">
            <div class="topo"></div>

            <div class="consumoTerminal">
                <h3>1 <span>GB</span></h3>
                <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
                <button class="detail"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terminal-alert">
            <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
    <div class="grafico">
        <div class="grafico-arc yellow">
            <div class="topo"></div>
            <div class="consumoTerminal">
                <h3>2 <span>GB</span></h3>
                <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
                <button class="detail"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terminal-alert">
            <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="sliderCard">
    <div class="grafico">
        <div class="grafico-arc red">
            <div class="topo"></div>
            <div class="consumoTerminal">
                <h3>3 <span>GB</span></h3>
                <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
                <button class="detail"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terminal-alert">
            <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Version**

You just need to run your function using a selector that matches both classes (green and grafico-arc).  Using this method there's no need for the extra conditional statement using hasClass:

```js
$(".grafico-arc.green").each(function() {
   $(this).siblings(".terminal-alert").css("display", "none");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">
    <div class="grafico-arc green">
      <div class="topo"></div>
      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>1 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">
    <div class="grafico-arc yellow">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>2 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">
    <div class="grafico-arc red">
      <div class="topo"></div>
      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>3 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you can do this with just some CSS, no JavaScript or jQuery needed:

```
.grafico-arc.green+.terminal-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
.grafico-arc.green+.terminal-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc green">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>1 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc yellow">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>2 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc red">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>3 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you just beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$(".terminal-alert")`

```js
$(".grafico-arc").each(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("green")) {
    $(this).siblings().css("display", "none");
    //---------------------^ // also you can use hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc green">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>1 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc yellow">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>2 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="sliderCard">
  <div class="grafico">

    <div class="grafico-arc red">
      <div class="topo"></div>

      <div class="consumoTerminal">
        <h3>3 <span>GB</span></h3>
        <p>(21) 98899-0805</p>
        <button class="detail"></button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="terminal-alert">
      <p>Saldo esgotando <a href="#">Mais internet</a></p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```